# How to make string with fragments from different strategies static?

Tags: java, string, static, sqlconnection

When we concatenate compile-time static Strings using the `+` operator, the compiler will join them together and store a new static string in its place.

Now I have a strategy pattern that supplies SQL fragments that should be concatenated into a larger SQL statement. All the pieces are static, but since there are method calls involved the above compile-time joining does not happen.

Example:

```
class MagicDao {
    void Object daoMethod(GetStuff cmd) {
        String sql = "select ... where " + cmd.getWhereClause() + " order by ...";
        // ...
    }
}

public interface GetStuff {
    String getWhereClause();

    Object[] getParameters();
}

class GetFunStuff implements GetStuff {
    public String getWhereClause() {
        return " abc = ? ";
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am wondering is there any pattern/trick that will make the SQL string concatenation compile-time again while retaining the simplicity/readability of the code above.

(If caching is the only solution, could one suggest a readable, thread-safe one liner?)

(Motivation for doing this: making things static will save countless garbage being created each second during the string building process and saves the time looking up the string in the `PreparedStatement` cache.)

Comment: Why are you concerned about this concatenation at compile time? How does it affect the code you have? **How much** time does it save?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how you're making SQL queries, but you could consider to use JDBC `PreparedStatement`, like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select ... where ? order by ...");
pstmt.setString(1, cmd.getWhereClause());
```

in this case your `String` will be precompiled

Comment: It is not possible to have SQL fragments (that is not a simiple value) as query parameters...